# Binding CustomDateEditor spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC with annotations. 
I havent registered any customDateEditory

In My Class i have one Property of type java.lang.Date

What i read was that customDateEditor are not registered by default. But when i submit my form  with blank date it throws illegalArgumentException

If i enter date and then submit it doesnt throws exception

THen after that i added BindingResult as argument to controller method now it is accepting blank values

I have not added any initbinder to my Controller

Controller

```
   @Controller("orderController")
   @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
    public class OrderController extends BaseController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewOrders.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewOrders(@ModelAttribute("searchOrder") SearchOrder       searchOrder,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model) {

        List<Order> orders=orderService.getOrders(searchOrder);
        model.addAttribute("orders", orders);

        return "order/searchOrder";
    }
    }
```

Pojo Containing Date Field

```
public class SearchOrder {

    private Integer orderId;
    private Long customerId;
    private String customerPo;
    private Date dateCreatedFrom;
    private Date dateCreatedTo;
    private Date dateUpdatedFrom;
    private Date dateUpdatedTo;


    public Integer getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public Long getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerPo() {
        return customerPo;
    }

    public void setCustomerPo(String customerPo) {
        this.customerPo = customerPo;
    }

    public Date getDateCreatedFrom() {
        return dateCreatedFrom;
    }

    public void setDateCreatedFrom(Date dateCreatedFrom) {
        this.dateCreatedFrom = dateCreatedFrom;
    }

    public Date getDateCreatedTo() {
        return dateCreatedTo;
    }

  public void setDateCreatedTo(Date dateCreatedTo) {
        this.dateCreatedTo = dateCreatedTo;
    } 

    public Date getDateUpdatedFrom() {
        return dateUpdatedFrom;
    }

    public void setDateUpdatedFrom(Date dateUpdatedFrom) {
        this.dateUpdatedFrom = dateUpdatedFrom;
    }

    public Date getDateUpdatedTo() {
        return dateUpdatedTo;
    }

    public void setDateUpdatedTo(Date dateUpdatedTo) {
        this.dateUpdatedTo = dateUpdatedTo;
    }

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchOrder [orderId=" + orderId + ", customerId=" + customerId
                + ", customerPo=" + customerPo + ", dateCreatedFrom="
            + dateCreatedFrom + ", dateCreatedTo=" + dateCreatedTo
                + ", dateUpdatedFrom=" + dateUpdatedFrom + ", dateUpdatedTo="
            + dateUpdatedTo + "]";
    } 


 }
```

Please throw some light

Comment: Please show your controller class and your class that contains the `Date`.

Comment: Hi Sotirios
I have added the code to the question.. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

When you add a [`BindingResult`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) than this binding result contains the information about the binding and validation that does not "work".
You can use [`BindingResult.hasErrors()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#hasErrors%28%29) to check if the binding result contains information about the "problem".

If you do not have a `BindingResult` method parameter, then Spring throw autoamticaly an exception if there is a binding error.

Add

```
 for(ObjectError objectError : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
       Sysout.println("error: " + objectError);
 }
```

to get some information about your binding error

---

(Btw: the method parameter order is important: the `BindingResult` parameter must be the next parameter after the Command object that should be checked with this `BindingResult`)

Comment: Hi Ralph

First of all Thank you for your help

So there is no need to register CustomDateEditor?

Comment: I only explained why "... I added BindingResult as argument to controller method now it is accepting blank values" 'works'